# Homeomorphic vs Homotopy Equivalent

Tags: general-topology

Now I know the definition of each of these, and I also know that homeomorphic implies homotopy equivalent.

However I seem to be coming across examples of spaces that are homeomorphic but not homotopy equivalent.

For example two interlocked circles are homeomorphic to two disjoint circles, via an obvious map, but you can't continuously deform the interlocked circles into the disjoint ones, so doesn't that mean they aren't homotopy equivalent?

I don't think I fully understand homotopy equivalence.

Comment: If you had a homotopy equivalence, how would it let you "continuously deform the interlocked circles into the disjoint ones"?  That's not the definition of a homotopy equivalence...

Comment: Do not use heuristic definitions until you are comfortable and understand examples of the actual definitions, or you'll run into trouble like this.

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing up homotopy equivalence of spaces with homotopy equivalence of maps. What you're talking about are two maps $S^1\to X$ where $X$ is $\Bbb R^3$ with a circle removed. Those maps are not homotopy equivalent; there is certainly no continuous way to deform an $S^1$ that is interlocked with the removed circle into one that isn't.

However, the space itself, i.e. the disjoint union of two circles without any reference to an ambient space is both homeomorphic and homotopy equivalent to itself.

Comment: I would have viewed his example rather as two maps of $S^1\times\{0,1\}\to\Bbb R^3$

Comment: I would too, but in that case, they are homotopy equivalent; is just that one $t_0\in [0,1]$ makes $H(x,t_0)$ non-injective. It's that non-injectivity that makes the OP feel that the two aren't homotopy equivalent, and that is most easily illustrated my way, I think.